# Extreme Lags In Games

Tags: wine, games

First of all here is my computer's specs..
Processor:
Model:Pentium 4 Prescott 2M 90NM
Architecture:x86_64
Speed:3GHZ
Features:NetBurst Technology,Hyper Threading Technology, Virtualization Technology

Ram:3GB

HDD:197GB Available

Graphics Properties:
Intel 82945G Express Chipset Family
Total Available Memory:256MB
Shared Memory:190MB
Dedicated Video Memory:0MB
System Video Memory:64MB

Currently Installed OS:
Ubuntu Mate LTS Bionic Beaver 64Bit 18.04(Latest)

So my problem is that in past when i used to have windows 7 and xp..i played a lot of games like Project IGI, Project IGI 2,Max Payne 1,2,Return To Castle Wolfenstein,Desert Storm,GTA Vice City etc.. These games are not at all graphics intensive and very old games and my hardware can support these games.

In windows 7 and XP i get 30FPS always in above games but i recently moved to Ubuntu Mate..I successfully installed wine and managed to run MS OFFICE,Photoshop and other Windows softwares as well as those games that i mentioned above.

The problem is game opens and run smoothly in main menu but when game starts it starts to lag like hell...2-5FPS..Help Me.I have updated all drivers.. every thing is latest..and with winecfg command i selected windows xp and added d3d9 and d3d8 libraries in wine.

What should i do?

Comment: Steam App? Just a suggestion...Maybe they can automate a lot of those services instead of emulating Windows.

Comment: Congrats on getting MS Office...I could install it but never could get it to Verify that I owned it so it would shut down on me..Has this improved?

Comment: Will try with steam app but i have pirated copies of those games...portable version..how can i run them using steam?

Comment: I have portable version of MS OFFICE 2010 which works fine for me and i use daily without any issues!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using games from Steam try to use MESA drivers.
If you are using Nvidia card 1060 or better i suggest you use vulkan in all you can.
The same for AMD graphic card.
Some games like "Doom 2016 (doom)" that you can play with proton it is better using Vulkan.
Don't forget check your stats on steam in  "help>sistem info" and check the vulkan is running on this.